# Pyspark: Extract Multiple Values from a column into new columns based on Spaces and Hyphens

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with column forenames. I have to create a new column first_name which has first string of characters before the first space or if hyphen occurs in first string of characters prior to first space within forenames.

```
|forenames        | first_name |
+--------+---------------------+
|IVO-KAI ROGERS   |  IVO-KAI   |
|DYLAN STUART JOHN|  DYLAN     |
|JOSH JACK        |  JOSH      |
|MONALISA ELIEN   |  MONALISA  |
|RACHEL- GREEN JOE|RACHEL-GREEN|
```

I have to create another new column middle_name which will have second string of characters from forenames after the first space followed by first_name. Expected Output will be:

```
|forenames        | first_name | middle_name |
+--------+---------------------+-------------+
|IVO-KAI ROGERS   |  IVO-KAI   | ROGERS      |
|DYLAN STUART JOHN|  DYLAN     | STUART JOHN |
|JOSH JACK        |  JOSH      | JACK        |
|MONALISA ELIEN   |  MONALISA  | ELIEN       |
|RACHEL- GREEN JOE|RACHEL-GREEN| JOE         |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To split the forenames column into first_name and last_name based on the first space occurrence, you can use SPLIT and SUBSTRING_INDEX functions in Spark SQL. Here's how you can achieve this.

```
scala> val dfa = spark.sql("SELECT  forenames, SUBSTRING_INDEX(forenames, ' ', 1) AS first_name, SUBSTRING(forenames, LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(forenames, ' ', 1)) + 2) AS last_name FROM df")
dfa: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [forenames: string, first_name: string ... 1 more field]

scala> dfa.show(false)

+-----------------+----------+-----------+
|forenames        |first_name|last_name  |
+-----------------+----------+-----------+
|IVO-KAI ROGERS   |IVO-KAI   |ROGERS     |
|DYLAN STUART JOHN|DYLAN     |STUART JOHN|
|JOSH JACK        |JOSH      |JACK       |
|MONALISA ELIEN   |MONALISA  |ELIEN      |
+-----------------+----------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pyspark code below to split the first column and create two news colums :

```
df.withColumn('first_name', split(df['forenames'], ' ').getItem(0))\
  .withColumn('last_name', concat_ws(" ",split(df['forenames'], ' ').getItem(1), split(df['forenames'], ' ').getItem(2) ))
```

Best regards,
Hissein

Comment: This wouldn't work for scenario where I have multiple words for middle name
Ex:
`|forenames        | first_name | middle_name |
+--------+---------------------+-------------+
|DYLAN STUART JOHN|  DYLAN     | STUART |`
It should give STUART JOHN in middle name

Comment: you have to add à concat to concatenate last 2 values of the colonne to get  **STUART JOHN** as    middle name :                                                                             `df = df.withColumn('first_name', split(df['forenames'], ' ').getItem(0))\
       .withColumn('last_name', concat_ws(" ",split(df['forenames'], ' ').getItem(1), split(df['forenames'], ' ').getItem(2) ))
df.show()`